# Why is this usage of the package MnSymbol raising an error?

Tags: font-encodings, xsavebox

Why does the following document raise an error?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\aeaesigbox
\savebox{\aeaesigbox}{$AE$AE}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newsavebox\aebox
\savebox\aebox{\fbox{$\filledmedsquare$}}

\begin{document}

  testing: \usebox\aebox
  $\filledmedsquare$

  \usebox\aeaesigbox

\end{document}
```

The error is reported as

```
! \textfont 6 is undefined (character ?).
<argument> $\filledmedsquare $
                              
l.9 \savebox\aebox{\fbox{$\filledmedsquare$}}
                                             
?
```

I'm not asking how to fix the error (at least not yet).  I can temporarily fix it loading the package `MnSymbol` before making any `savebox` calls.  Such as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newsavebox\aeaesigbox
\savebox{\aeaesigbox}{$AE$AE}

\newsavebox\aebox
\savebox\aebox{\fbox{$\filledmedsquare$}}

\begin{document}

  testing: \usebox\aebox
  $\filledmedsquare$

  \usebox\aeaesigbox

\end{document}
```

But why this makes a difference, I don't understand.  The MWE's above are exactly that.  They show the error (at least on my computer) where I'm working with TeX Live 2021.

Comment: fonts are not really set up until begin document, in simple cases you may get lucky and a savebox works, but in general it will give this sort of error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, would you recommend that I put my `\savebox` commands into an `\AtEndPreamble` or similar such construction?  That way they're in the packages I've defined and I don't have to worry about such errors then arising?

Comment: yes, exactly...